# How to take the output to a file to be created automatically where the output values are changeable by running a function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create file automatically (i.e. file00,file01....) based on the values of Lists.

The first list (i.e "Unique_Cluster") having values 0 to 79.
Besides there is a function which will give the 2nd  list as output (i.e. "output"). The "output" data is supposed to be changed every time while running the function. Now, I need to store the changeable values of the list "output" every time in a file. 
I am getting the response as expected but only for the 1st item in the list i.e. for 0 only. Rest of the file has been created automatically but the value inside the file is empty

what I did:
1. define the function "clustIP" which is giving the list for output as "output"
2. Running the list "Unique_Cluster" as for loop and calling the function for each value of "Unique_Cluster" i.e. values 0 to 79. The loop format is structured in such a way that the "output" list will be cleared of every time after storing the value in dynamically creatrd json file.

```
output=list()

# function for taking the values/output within a list (i.e. output)

def clustIP(uc_val):
    if uc_val <= 79:
        for ln in f2:
            pieces=re.split('"|"|:|,',ln)
            if int(pieces[3])==uc_val and pieces[8] not in  output:
                output.append(pieces[8])
    else:
        print("out of range")

# running loop of list (i.e.Unique_Cluster, whose value ranges from 0   t0 79) 
# every run will execute the above function .
# After running the function, will give different "output" that will be stored in file created dynamically.
# The output is cleared off after saving it into file. This is because  new output value will be stored inside the output list for every value of the list "Unique_Cluster".

for i in Unique_Cluster:
    clustIP(i)
    i= int(i)
    f = open('file%02d.json' % i, 'w')
    json.dump(output,f)
    f.close()
    output.clear()
```

Actual Result vs Expected Result :
For the first file i.e. file00 is giving the value as below which is perfect.

```
["xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa",
 "xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa",
 "................"]
```

but for rest of the file I am getting blank list i.e. []
 which is not perfect. because this file should also some values as per the code.

Comment: What is `f2`? Is it a previously opened file, by chance?

Comment: yeah this is another file from which the value will be stored into the list i.e. output if matches the criteria.

Comment: Then the whole content of the file is read when you call `clustIP(i)` for the first time. For all consecutive calls, the file is empty. You should either open/close the file in the function or, better, read it before the first call to `clustlP` and save the content in a list.

Comment: Are you meaning that the file f2 will be empty for the next consecutive calls after first time?What I am  doing is to clear the output list only after saving the contents into a file. So, the file f2 will have the same contents as previous and cluster(i) function should work on it. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: You read the file to the end in the first call and never rewind or reopen it. For all consecutive calls, the iterator associated with the file is empty. There is nothing more to read.

Comment: Hey @TaskinAlamJim, I have tried to take suggestions made below and some more fixes and tried to fix up you code, take a look

Comment: Hi @ DYZ,  Got the themes and I understood now. Thank you for your nice and kind explanation and cooperation.

Comment: Hi Devesh Kumar Singh, I got it. The code is working perfectly as I expected. Thank you for your support and cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by a commentor, `f2` which supposedly is an already opened file object is read in it's entirety, and then never read again, since you don't close the file object, so it is better that you open the file and read the contents of that file before you start your `Unique_Cluster` loop, and then use those contents.

You can also use `with` context manager to open and close the json file automatically.

In addition, `output` variable can be defined inside `clustIP` function itself, and then returned from it

So the code might look as follows

```
#Read the content of f2 behorehand
f2_lines = []
with open('file_f2.txt') as f2:
    f2_lines = f2.readlines()

# function for taking the values/output within a list (i.e. output)

def clustIP(uc_val):

    #Define output variable locally
    output = []
    if uc_val <= 79:
        #Use the content read above here
        for ln in f2_lines:
            pieces=re.split('"|"|:|,',ln)
            if int(pieces[3])==uc_val and pieces[8] not in  output:
                output.append(pieces[8])
    else:
        print("out of range")

    #Return output variable here
    return output

# running loop of list (i.e.Unique_Cluster, whose value ranges from 0   t0 79) 
# every run will execute the above function .
# After running the function, will give different "output" that will be stored in file created dynamically.
# The output is cleared off after saving it into file. This is because  new output value will be stored inside the output list for every value of the list "Unique_Cluster".

for i in Unique_Cluster:

    #Output is taken fron clustIP
    output = clustIP(i)

    i= int(i)
    with open('file%02d.json' % i, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(output,f)
```